# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6

This is my form in .ts

```
 this.editForm = this.fb.group({
    'dropoffs': this.fb.array(this.createDropOffFacility(data.dropoffs.filter(picks => picks.drop_facility !== ''))),
});


 createDropOffFacility(facilities) {
     const controls = facilities.map((drop) => this.fb.group({
     drop_facility: drop.drop_facility
  }));
   return controls;
 }
```

That happens when drop_facility is empty, but if not empty, it just fine

the line in dropoffs throws the error. Now with that existing, how to check if the filter is empty or undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution might be to pass `data.dropoffs` into your `createDropOffFacility()` through which you can ensure that the filter is being called on an array by setting the argument's default property.

```
this.editForm = this.fb.group({
    'dropoffs': this.fb.array(this.createDropOffFacility(data.dropoffs)),
});

createDropOffFacility(dropoffs: any[] = []) {
    const facilities = dropoffs.filter(picks => picks.drop_facility !== '')
    const controls = facilities.map((drop) => this.fb.group({
        drop_facility: drop.drop_facility
    }));
    return controls;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you ?

```
 this.editForm = (data && data.dropoffs) ? this.fb.group({
    'dropoffs': this.fb.array(this.createDropOffFacility(data.dropoffs.filter(picks => picks.drop_facility !== ''))) : '',
});
```